# window.print() cut some content but no other

Tags: php, html, css, printing

Im doing a page to visualice the content of some tables(mysql) and then I thought to do a button to print this tables but some tables cut the content. I will post the table to print and some images.

The code of the table to print:

```
<?php
$a = $index - 1;
echo "<div id='{$a}' class='table-responsive d-block'>"
?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $val = [];
            $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$valor}";
            $result = $connection->query($sql);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<th class='text-secondary col-md-auto text-capitalize'>{$row['Field']}</th>";
                $val[] = $row['Field'];
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$valor}";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            echo ("No se encontro resultado");
            die("Invalid query: " . $connection->error);
        }
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($val as &$campo) {
                if (isset($row['Link']) && !empty($row['Link'])) {
                    echo "<td class='text-primary' id='{$campo}'><a style='text-decoration: none;' target='_blank' href='{$row['Link']}'>$row[$campo]</a></td>";
                } elseif (isset($row['Marca']) && isset($row['Modelo']) && !empty($row['Marca']) && !empty($row['Modelo'])) {
                    echo "<td class='text-primary' id='{$campo}'><a style='text-decoration: none;' target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com/search?q={$row['Marca']}+{$row['Modelo']}'>$row[$campo]</a></td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td class='text-primary' id='{$campo}'>$row[$campo]</td>";
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And some examples:

[Perfect example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrUqH.png)
[Bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aJ4d.jpg)

please... I'm trying to make the question clear, to answer well and to do my best, don't ban my post as usual or insult me. English is not my forte either, I do what I can, constructive criticism would help me much more.

I only want that table with long link, dont be cut.
Maybe a solution is deleting links and write shorcuts?

Comment: Using a URL shorter like https://www.shorturl.at works, but it not the solution im looking for.

Comment: Not really sure what you want here. The two tables seem to be different in several regards, so I'm not sure exactly what you want. You could add the links and just have something like: `Link` as the link text? The link text can be anything, really.

Comment: Both tables are generated the same, it depends on the information that the table has, it will be generated in one way or another. But maybe the solution is like you said and delenting the complete URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I got the solution:

```
class='text-wrap'
```

From boostrap.

That's works too:

```
@media print { 
  table,
  table tr td,
  table tr th {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```